# How to uninstall a TrueType font?

Tags: fonts, software-uninstall, .ttf

I have installed a font, and now I wish to remove it, but I am not sure exactly how.
I installed it by opening the `.TTF` file and clicking the "Install" button. But there is no uninstall button, and no obvious way of uninstalling a font installed in that way.

So my question is really obvious, how do I uninstall a font installed in that way?